# How to change indentation of specific comment in algorithmic environment?

Tags: comments, algorithmic

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcounter{ALC@tempcntr}% Temporary counter for storage
\newcommand{\LCOMMENT}[1]{%
    \setcounter{ALC@tempcntr}{\arabic{ALC@rem}}% Store old counter
    \setcounter{ALC@rem}{1}% To avoid printing line number
    \item //#1 % Display comment + does not increment list item counter
    \setcounter{ALC@rem}{\arabic{ALC@tempcntr}}% Restore old counter
}%

\begin{document} 
        
    \begin{algorithm}[!t]
        \caption{A sample algorithm.}
        \textbf{Input:}  Some input.\\
        \textbf{Output:} Some output.
        
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \LCOMMENT {1st Step:}
            \STATE Do something.
            \LCOMMENT {2nd Step:} 
            \IF {$A \geq B$}
            \STATE Do something.
            \LCOMMENT {3rd Step:}
            \ELSE 
            \STATE Do something.            
            \ENDIF
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following algorithm. Note that I use a new command for comment (i.e. \LCOMMENT) in order to have comments starting with // and, more importantly, to not use line numbering for comments.
However, in the above case, I would like the 3rd comment to have the same indentation as the next line in the algorithm (i.e. line 4) and not the same indentation as line 3. Is there a simple way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each level beyond the first `algorithmic` adds `\algorithmicindent` to the current indentation. One can access the level by looking at `\@listdepth`, so we need to add a negative space of `\@listdepth-1` times `\algorithmicindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcounter{ALC@tempcntr}% Temporary counter for storage
\newcommand{\LCOMMENT}[1]{%
    \setcounter{ALC@tempcntr}{\arabic{ALC@rem}}% Store old counter
    \setcounter{ALC@rem}{1}% To avoid printing line number
    \item \removemargin // #1 % Display comment + does not increment list item counter
    \setcounter{ALC@rem}{\arabic{ALC@tempcntr}}% Restore old counter
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removemargin}{\hspace*{\numexpr1-\@listdepth\relax\algorithmicindent}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
        
    \begin{algorithm}[!t]
        \caption{A sample algorithm.}
        \textbf{Input:}  Some input.\\
        \textbf{Output:} Some output.
        
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \LCOMMENT {1st Step:}
            \STATE Do something.
            \LCOMMENT {2nd Step:} 
            \IF {$A \geq B$}
            \STATE Do something.
            \LCOMMENT {3rd Step:}
\IF{x}\STATE a \LCOMMENT {what?}\ELSE \STATE b \ENDIF % to show further indentation
            \ELSE 
            \STATE Do something.            
            \ENDIF
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]